# single.php loop outputs duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, posts

My blog posts sometimes output in multiple instances. This happens randomly but when it occurs the only solution I have is to remove the post and repost it again.

The problem can be seen live here: http://experienceinvest.com/british-student-housing-investment-to-hit-5-75bn/

My single.php file:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); rewind_posts(); }  ?>

<?php

if ('investment' == get_post_type()) { include("investment-single.php");}
else { include("news-single.php"); }

?>
```

Comment: the code must be repeated or the single.php is included twice

Comment: This happens on random bases, If the code was being repeated twice it would effect all posts.

Comment: Why are you using `rewind_posts()` in this way? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts

Comment: Does it appears for particular post every time?

Comment: dingo_d: If I don't use rewind_posts() within that loop wordpress just continuously loops until the page crashes. adding that will rewind and pause the loop after the first loop.

Comment: parag: Thanks for your interest and time, I have fixed it with the below soluttion.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The content of both **single.php** and the **single template files**, in this case invstment-single.php & news-single.php needed to be wrapped in the following loop.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); rewind_posts(); ?>

<!--The page content goes here-->

<?php endif; ?>
```